# List of class objects - Filter class objects with same values using LINQ

Tags: linq, list

I am using a class object (clsDetails)  to store the player details as shown below. I am trying to filter a list of Class objects with same values using LINQ.

I want to get the list of Players who are successful in all the 5 attempts. I am trying to do it using LINQ but it does not return the correct players.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<clsDetails> lstAllDetails = new List<clsDetails>();
            try
            {
                clsDetails cd;

            //Player 1
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId =1, sPlayerId="P1",sPlayerSuccess="YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 2, sPlayerId = "P1", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 3, sPlayerId = "P1", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 4, sPlayerId = "P1", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 5, sPlayerId = "P1", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);


            //Player 2
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 1, sPlayerId = "P2", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 2, sPlayerId = "P2", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 3, sPlayerId = "P2", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 4, sPlayerId = "P2", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 5, sPlayerId = "P2", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);

            //Player 3
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 1, sPlayerId = "P3", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 2, sPlayerId = "P3", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 3, sPlayerId = "P3", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 4, sPlayerId = "P3", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 5, sPlayerId = "P3", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);

            //Player 4
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 1, sPlayerId = "P4", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 2, sPlayerId = "P4", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 3, sPlayerId = "P4", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 4, sPlayerId = "P4", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 5, sPlayerId = "P4", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);

            //Player 5
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 1, sPlayerId = "P5", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 2, sPlayerId = "P5", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 3, sPlayerId = "P5", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 4, sPlayerId = "P5", sPlayerSuccess = "NO" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 5, sPlayerId = "P5", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);

            //Player 6
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 1, sPlayerId = "P6", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 2, sPlayerId = "P6", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 3, sPlayerId = "P6", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 4, sPlayerId = "P6", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);
            cd = new clsDetails() { iAttemptId = 5, sPlayerId = "P6", sPlayerSuccess = "YES" };
            lstAllDetails.Add(cd);

            //players successfull in first attempt itself
            var vSuccessFirstAttempt = (from d in lstAllDetails
                                        where d.sPlayerSuccess.ToUpper() == "YES" && d.iAttemptId == 1
                                        select d.sPlayerId);

            //Players successfull in all the 5 attempts
            var vSuccessAllAttempts = (from d in lstAllDetails
                                       group d by new {d.sPlayerId,d.sPlayerSuccess} into grp
                                        where grp.Count() ==1 && grp.Key.sPlayerSuccess =="YES"
                                        select grp.Key.sPlayerId);

            // vSuccessAllAttempts - Enumeration yielded No result

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
    }

}

public class clsDetails
{
    public int iAttemptId = 0;
    public string sPlayerId = string.Empty;
    public string sPlayerSuccess = string.Empty;
}
```

I also want to get

1. List of players who are successful in the first attempt itself
2. List of player who are successful in first or second attempt
3. List of players who are successful in at least 3 attempts.
4. List of players who are successful in all the 5 attempts

I am not sure what is the issue with the below query and why it does not return any value.

```
var vSuccessAllAttempts = (from d in lstAllDetails
                                           group d by new {d.sPlayerId,d.sPlayerSuccess} into grp
                                            where grp.Count() ==1 && grp.Key.sPlayerSuccess =="YES"
                                            select grp.Key.sPlayerId);
```

Thanks 
Ashok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define two methods:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetPlayersSuccessfullInAttempt(IEnumerable<clsDetails> players, int attempt)
{
    return players.Where(p=>p.sPlayerSuccess = "YES" && p.iAttemptId == attempt)
        .Select(p => p.sPlayerId);
}

private IEnumerable<string> GetPlayersSuccessfullInAllAttempts(IEnumerable<clsDetails> players, int numberOfAttempts)
{
    return players.GroupBy(p => p.sPlayerId)
        .Where(g => g.Count(p => p.sPlayerSuccess >= "YES") == numberOfAttempts)
        .Select(g => g.Key); //g.Key is the player Id
}
```

And now, to get the results:

```
var playersSuccessfullInFirstAttempt = GetPlayersSuccessfullInAttempt(lstAllDetails, 1);
var playersSuccessfullInFirstOrSecondAttempt = playersSuccessfullInFirstAttempt
    .Union(GetPlayersSuccessfullInAttempt(lstAllDetails, 2))
    .Distinct();

var successfullInAtLeast3 = GetPlayersSuccessfullInAllAttempts(lstAllDetails, 3);
var successfullInAll5 = GetPlayersSuccessfullInAllAttempts(lstAllDetails, 5);
```

And here are the results in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

[image: Query results.]

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the players successful at all attempts:

```
var vSuccessAllAttempts = (from d in lstAllDetails
                           group d by new {d.sPlayerId,d.sPlayerSuccess} into grp
                           where grp.Count() == 5 && grp.Key.sPlayerSuccess =="YES"
                           select grp.Key.sPlayerId);
```

Comment: if it helped you, please consider accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following also.

```
Func<IEnumerable<clsDetails>, int, IEnumerable<String>> successfulInNthAttempt =
    (p, n) =>
    p.Where(x => x.sPlayerSuccess == "YES" && x.iAttemptId == n)
        .Select(x => x.sPlayerId);

Func<IEnumerable<clsDetails>, int, bool, IEnumerable<String>>successfulInAllNAttempts =
    (p, n, isExact) =>
    p.Where(x => x.sPlayerSuccess == "YES")
        .GroupBy(y => new {y.sPlayerId, y.sPlayerSuccess})
        .Where(z => isExact? z.Count() == n: z.Count()>= n)
        .Select(x => x.Key.sPlayerId);

var attempt1 =successfulInNthAttempt(lstAllDetails, 1);
var attempt1Or2 = successfulInNthAttempt(lstAllDetails, 1).Union(successfulInNthAttempt(lstAllDetails, 2)).Distinct();
var atLeast3Attempts = successfulInAllNAttempts(lstAllDetails, 3, false);
var all5Attempts = successfulInAllNAttempts(lstAllDetails, 5, true);
```